# VXML getting 'src' for subdialog from variable

Tags: voice, vxml, coexistence

Our business is transitioning from an old asp system to a newer ASP.NET system, including massive improvements to our database.  There is going to be a period of coexistence, during which old & new will run side-by-side.

One app which needs coexistence is a voicemail system we use.  It works as follows:

1. User calls.
2. User inputs an account number.
3. User records message for that account.
4. User gets option to re-record, accept, or discard.

During coexistence, the existing app is being modified.  When a user enters an account number which has been converted to the new system (which uses different identifying numbers) we want to seamlessly allow them to proceed.  The account verification system is currently returning the account name, the account number, and (for coexistence) the path to the correct recording page.

Once the user has recorded a message and accepted it (or hung up), we fire a subdialog to record the message to our database.

How can I modify the subdialog call to accept the content of a variable as the src?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `srcexpr` instead.  Here is an example

```
<var name="VariableHere" expr="'nowhere.vxml'"/>
<!-- Populate your VariableHere through your logic, default to nowhere.vxml --> 
<subdialog srcexpr="'http://www.YourDomain.com/' + VariableHere">
</subdialog>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to be what I was looking for.