# VXML Beep at recording timeout

Tags: voice, vxml, voicemail

The VXML application I mentioned [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640255/vxml-getting-src-for-subdialog-from-variable) is now in testing.  After allowing the user to record a message (max length 5 minutes) we go into a standard menu (submit, playback, re-record, etc).

One of our testers, bored as anything and tired of leaving a 5-minute message was reading an email we had sent, including the phone number.  She said 'Two' just after the menu started, having heard only a split second of the menu.

Needless to say, she was very confused.

The right way to fix this, to me, seems to be to add a definitive stop to the recording, like the beep that begins it.

The [record item](http://www.vxml.org/frame.jsp?page=record.htm) has a beep property that beeps at the start of the recording, which we use.  I can't find reference to any property that would beep when the user reaches max time.

How can I add an uninterruptible beep at the end of a  when it has reached the maxtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a bit more digging tells me that there's no property for it on the  object.

But I did turn up a property on the resulting variable 'maxtime' that tells you if it ended due to a maximum time exceeded event.

By checking that in the  section, but before sending them to the menu, I am able to use an  block to play an audio file with bargein="false"

It's a bit more code than I'd like, but it seems to work.